# Initialise array - brackets before or after identifier?

Tags: java

I think I have seen both patterns in Java:

```
int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

Are they both correct? Why are they both correct? Is one of them preferred/recommended?

My question is: when does the `[]` go after the type, and when does the `[]` go after the identifier when initialising arrays?

Comment: Multidimensional arrays add even more spice: `int[][] array`, `int[] array[]`, `int []array[]`

Comment: @ernest_k `int array[][]` too?

Comment: Yep, that too .